# Laravel Eloquent self relation query to return nested JSON

Tags: json, laravel, api, eloquent

I have a table with an one-to-one self relationship to represent an hierarchical structure. Below are the diagram of the Table and a few sample data:

[image: Locations Table]
[image: Example Data]

This is the Location model code for the relationship:

```
class Location extends Model
{
    public function location()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Location');
    }
}
```

I would like to query the Locations table and send a JSON response like the example below but I'm not sure how to approach the Query:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Country",
    "location_id": null
    "location": {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "State",
        "location_id": 1
        "location": {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "City",
            "location_id": 2
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be a one to many relationship? One country can have many cities but one city can only be in one country. The approach to the query depends on how you want to play it really, if you have potentially millions of records, do you want to load all of them and show them all? Maybe you only want to show so many levels, or perhaps just the immediate children? There are many different ways you can do it so the answer really depends on what you want.

Comment: Whats the anticipated depth? 2, 4, 10, 20 levels?

Comment: @Jonathon This is just an example I'm sure my project will only require a linear hierarchy

Comment: @Kyslik The depth will be dynamic any number of location can be nested

Comment: Are you willing to use PostgresSQL? I doubt (who knows) you can do this in Eloquent itself, you can try https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_and_recursive_queries_in_SQL Also how many location is going to be there in the whole table? 1k, 100k? 1m? You can just grab all locations and do it in PHP.

Comment: @Kyslik I'm using mysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To always eager load the location relation and not worry about depth, you could add the $with property to your location model:

```
protected $with = ['location'];
```

Now when you return a location, it will have all nested sub locations loaded up:

```
return App\Location::find(1);
```

Laravel also handles returning this as JSON if it's returned from a controller method.

*as pointed out by Kyslik, this presents a potential N+1 problem, potential depth along with query size and the rest of the environment should be considered when deciding to use a solution like this in production, for something like locations, it's probably not an issue and well worth the simlpicity*

Comment: Yep, but that's n+1 problem. As OP suggested it can be hundreds nested locations, in that case its better to load everything and just do it in pure PHP.

Comment: This works but what do I do if I ever need to turn `with` off?

Comment: Can op confirm that it could be hundreds of levels deep?  I think op just didn't want to give a specific number but I imagine if it's truly being used for locations this is still a viable option.

Comment: @mattQuest no it's not gonna be 100 level deep

Comment: I'm not sure that you can turn off the eager loading when it's set on the model like that, it's a potential drawback but I'd recommend not solving problems that aren't likely to occur.  Do you anticipate this becoming a performance issue?

Comment: Further, you can set it up this way and continue on writing your business logic which should be independent of how the data is stored and retrieved anyways, then choose to keep or rework this when you have a much better idea of what's required.

Comment: @mattQuest I think I'll limit the user to having only a few (7, 8) child locations it should be enough to serve their purpose so performance won't be an issue, Thanks

Comment: Should you ever need high performance hierarchical data in Laravel, check out https://github.com/lazychaser/laravel-nestedset